# What changes should I do in this code so that the two threads go till the end of the Array and print all of its content

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, producer-consumer

I am trying to print all numbers in the Array, starting from 1 at index 0 and ending at 11 at last.
There are two threads which are doing this one is printing only  the even number and second is printing only the odd numbers.

Here is the code.

```
class PrintEvenOdd {
      
    static class SourceData {
      
         int[] arr;
         volatile int counter;

         public SourceData(int[] commonArr, int counter){
           
             this.arr = commonArr;
             this.counter = counter;
         }

         public void getData(){
           try{
             synchronized(this){
                    
                 while((counter%2==0 && Thread.currentThread().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("odd")) || (counter%2!=0 && Thread.currentThread().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("even"))){
                    wait();
                 }

                 System.out.println(counter+ " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                 notify();
             }
           }catch(Exception ie){
              ie.printStackTrace();
           }
         }

    }

    static class Even extends Thread{
      SourceData sd;

      public Even(SourceData sd){
          this.sd = sd;        
      }

      @Override
      public void run(){
        while(sd.counter < 12) {   
         sd.getData();
         sd.counter++;
        }
      }
    }

    static class Odd extends Thread{
      SourceData sd;
      

      public Odd(SourceData sd){
         this.sd = sd;
      }

      @Override
      public void run(){
        while(sd.counter < 12) {  
         sd.getData();
         sd.counter++;
        }
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
       int[] commonArr = new int[11];
       for(int i = 0; i < commonArr.length; i++){
         commonArr[i] = i;  
       }
       int counter = 0;
   
       SourceData sd = new SourceData(commonArr, counter);
         Even even = new Even(sd);
         even.setName("EVEN");
         even.start();
         Odd odd = new Odd(sd);
         odd.setName("ODD");
         odd.start();
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that its printing only the two values, shown here,

```
0 : EVEN
1 : ODD
```

What changes should I do so that the code prints all the values till the end of the array?

Comment: What is the purpose of the arr data member for the SourceData class? You never use that data member.

Comment: Yes, I should have removed it, its never being used here. The while loop while(sd.counter < 12), in the run method, does the work for me, I initially wanted to get the work with the array. But later I felt that I did n't needed it.But its still left there in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening: EVEN runs, increments the counter to 1, and then in the next `getData` it starts waiting. Then ODD runs, increments the counter to 2, and then it too starts waiting in `getData`. You have two threads waiting with no chances of waking up.

To fix it, you have to notify when the condition a thread is waiting on changes. That is: notify after `sd.counter++`, so the other thread can wake up. Since the other thread is waiting on `sd`, you have to call:

```
sd.counter++
sd.notify()
```

Also note that ODD and EVEN threads are identical. You can have one class implementing the thread, and create two instances of it.

Comment: I have kept the sd.counter++ after the call to the sd.getData in the run methods of the two threads, obviously the threads are not seeing that, is this an example of visibility problem here? Please kindly explain.

Comment: sd.counter is declared volatile. Any modifications to it are visible to all the threads. Why do you think the threads are not seeing that? You still have a race though: you check sd.counter and increment it. Nothing prevents the other thread from coming in an incrementing before that. You should occasionally see array index out of bounds exceptions because of that.